# syntax error in ipython when creating 'class'

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am struggling to understand why I cannot execute this code? I keep getting a syntax error (line 6) when I do. Any ideas :( ?

```
from collections import Counter

def Edistance(x1, x2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x1-x2)**2)

class KNN:
    
    def _init_(self, k=3):
        self.k = k
        
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.X_Train = X
        self.y_Train = y
    
    
    def predict(self, X):
        predicted_labels = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(predicted_labels)
        
    def _predict(self, x):
        distances = [Edistance(x, x_train) for x_train in self.X_Train]
        k_indices = np.argsort(distances)[:self.k]
        k_nearest_labels = [self.y_Train[i] for i in k_indices]
        most_common = Counter(k_nearest_labels).most_common(1)
        return most_common[0][0]
```

File " < ipython-input-388-25faf7c817d3 > ", line 6
class KNN:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try removing the empty line after the classdef

Comment: It should be double underscore `__init__()` not single

Comment: Missing a `)` in your `Edistance` function. It should be `def Edistance(x1, x2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x1-x2)**2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close brackets at line 4, so add one bracket at the end of line 4.

P.S. Constructor is `__init__` , but you wrote `_init_`

Comment: Thanks you where right. It would have been helpful if the error message pointed to the correct line!